# how to get recursive filename and stored it into array in php

Tags: php, file-io

I have a function getting the recursive folder's filename inside a specific path:

```
function getDirectory( $path = '.', $level = 0 ){

$ignore = array( 'cgi-bin', '.', '..');
// Directories to ignore when listing output. Many hosts
// will deny PHP access to the cgi-bin.

$dh = @opendir( $path );
// Open the directory to the handle $dh
$files_matched = array(); 


while( false !== ( $file = readdir( $dh ) ) ){
// Loop through the directory

    if( !in_array($file, $ignore ) && !preg_match("/^.*\.(rar|txt)$/", $file) ){
    // Check that this file is not to be ignored

        if( is_dir( "$path/$file" ) ){
        // Its a directory, so we need to keep reading down...

            echo "<strong>$spaces $file</strong><br />";

            getDirectory( "$path/$file", ($level+1) );
            // Re-call this same function but on a new directory.
            // this is what makes function recursive.

        } else {
            $files_matched[$i] = $file;
            $i++;
        }

    }

}

closedir( $dh );
// Close the directory handle
return $files_matched;
}

echo "<pre>";
$files = getDirectory("F:\Test");
foreach($files as $file) printf("%s<br />", $file);
echo "</pre>";
```

I used $files_matched to stored the filename in an array.

And for the above result, it only display the filename under "F:\test".

Actually, I have a sub-folder under "F:\test". How can I display those filename using the array for storage?

If I modified the code:

```
$files_matched[$i] = $file;
$i++;
```

into:

```
echo "$files<br />";
```

This will be worked fine and I just don't know why use array to store the filename for later process is not work??

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you try initializing your array and $i variable above your loop?

Comment: What output do you see? Do you have errors turned on?

Comment: For one, you are not collecting the results from the recursive `getDirectory` call within. Also, there are existing solutions for that, namely RecursiveDirectoryIterator.

Comment: Should i suggest to use RecursiveDirectoryIterator with FilterIterator / CallbackFilterIterator? Your code would be much simpler. http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php

Comment: Landon: How to initializing the array and $i var ?? The current output is showing the filename only but there is no filename displayed inside the recursive sub-directory.

Comment: mario: So, is there any example code for me to retrieve filename of recursive folders? I need the storage in array for later other process in code...

Comment: pozs: I am confused with this so I using the traditional way to do it, in the info that you provided, which function(s) should I use for? any sample code can reference to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember where I got this code from, but it works.

```
<?php

function getDirectoryTree( $outerDir , $x){
    $dirs = array_diff( scandir( $outerDir ), Array( ".", ".." ) );
    $dir_array = Array();
    foreach( $dirs as $d ){
        if( is_dir($outerDir."/".$d)  ){
            $dir_array[ $d ] = getDirectoryTree( $outerDir."/".$d , $x);
        }else{
            if (($x)?ereg($x.'$',$d):1)
            $dir_array[ $d ] = $d;
        }
    }
    return $dir_array;
}

var_dump( getDirectoryTree(getcwd(),'') );
```

Comment: Your host has probably disabled this, and likely other functions. Try feeding it an actual path like 'f:/' or './'. If it still doesn't work then you should be talking to your hosting provider.

Comment: ok, thanks so much. but how to rewrite the regular expression for filtering the extension of file? like .txt or .dat?

Comment: The second argument for the function matches file extensions. If you want to match more than one at a time you'll have to modify the line `if (($x)?ereg($x.'$',$d):1)`

Comment: ok, but how can I get filename in recursive folder with this code??                 $files[] = getDirectoryTree("F:\TEST",'');
print $files[1]; //I need store the files in each array and later for other process

Comment: `print_r($files)` or `var_dump($files)` and figure out what you want to do.