# Why can't I return multiple values in array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to return multiple values from a PHP function, but it did not work as following codes:

The function is used to search the filenames in the specific folder and its recursive folders and store the filenames in the array.

**In this example, the specific (main) folder is called: F:\test**
**The recursive folder is called: F:\test\subfolder**

The main folder and subfolder carries 7 files, the filename formats are:

**For main folder: 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, 4.txt**
**For subfolder: 5.txt, 6.txt, 7.txt**

```
function getDirectory( $path = '.', $level = 0 ) {
$i=0;$j=0;

$dh = @opendir( $path );
while( false !== ( $file = readdir( $dh ) ) ){
// Loop through the directory

        if( is_dir( "$path/$file" ) ){
        // Its a directory, so we need to keep reading down...

            getDirectory( "$path/$file", ($level+1) );
            // Re-call this same function but on a new directory, this is what makes function recursive.

        } else {
            if ($level>0) //in a recursive folder
            {
                $dir_matched[$j]=$file;
                $j++;
            }
            else //in main folder
            {
            $files_matched[$i] = $file;
            $i++;
            }               
        }    
}
closedir( $dh );
//print_r ($files_matched);
//print_r ($dir_matched);   I tested this before return, both works fine.

return array($files_matched,$dir_matched);
}



echo "<pre>";
list($a,$b) = getDirectory("F:\test");
print_r ($a);   // this will result the same as array $files_matched, it ok!
print_r ($b);   // but i don't know why I cannot get the array of $dir_matched??
echo "</pre>";
```

As you can see, it is so strange that I can only get one array only? Is there any idea I can get the contents of the `$dir_matched` array?

Comment: In recursive functions you have to make sure that a recursive call is propagated back to the total result

Comment: Why do you keep asking the same thing? You got lots of better alternatives last time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036110/how-to-get-recursive-filename-and-stored-it-into-array-in-php

Comment: This is all you need : http://pastebin.com/Jixdq7JZ

Comment: Baba: It result the error, Fatal error:  Class 'FilesystemIterator' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it is written now, you are not capturing the values from the recursive call.  Within your function, on this line:

```
getDirectory( "$path/$file", ($level+1) );
```

You need to capture the returned values from it.  Something like:

```
$files_matched[++$i] = getDirectory( "$path/$file", ($level+1));
```

`$i` may not what you want here, you'll need to increment it here also like you do in your `else statement`, or else capture them in a different variable to reflect a subdirectory - depends on what you want to accomplish.